# electron get URL of local javascript file and return that

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome-extension, electron

I'm trying to mimmick some behavior that is easily achieved in chrome extentions, right now my app is getting bigger and I'm trying to rebuild in into electron as a standalone app.

Sadly I'm Running into an issue, I try to supply my own js for a certain webpage. In chrome extentions I would achieve that the following way:

```
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(function (details) {
        console.log("Patched init.js");
        return {redirectUrl: chrome.extension.getURL("init.js")};
    }, {urls: ["https://example.com/js/init.js"]}, ["blocking"]);
```

I just can't find the correct way to do so in electron. I really need it to return the local modified js file.

What I can use for the onBeforeRequest, but sadly I still don't have the local file like a chrome extention would (the getUrl function).

```
session.defaultSession.webRequest.onBeforeRequest(function (details) {
        console.log("Patched jQuery");
        return {redirectUrl: getUrlFunctionNeeded("init")};
    }, {urls: ["https://example.com/js/init.js"]}, ["blocking"]);

Best regards
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone is interested in the solution, I figured that creating a small web server with node-static within the electron app would suffice. I then use the localhost:port/staticmap/my.js as URL, instead of extention.getURL().